# Asp.net 5 mvc 6 action filter with iserviceProvider dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

when registering your filter in startup, how can you pass in an instance of IServiceProvider?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(o =>
        {

            o.Filters.Add(new MyFilterAttribute(???)); //how to get IServiceProvider
        });
}

public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public MyFilterAttribute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
     var myService = (IMyService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
  }
}
```

Comment: [May be related](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(o =>
{
    o.Filters.Add(new ServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(MyFilterAttribute)));

});

factory.RegisterType(typeof(MyFilterAttribute)).InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Beat me to it. There is a good explanation of how this works (and an alternative approach) [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/).